# How get the html svg element output from an array in php?

Tags: php

I have array with the svg element. I have to print it out from the listed array. i have tried to print it but it is not working. Please guide me how to get the svg element rendered on the browser.
actualy there are other items in the array i didnt show bcoz of character limit how to loop through the svg tag elements

```
  foreach($items as $item){
   print_r($item);        
      }

             [type] => text
[remove] => 1
[rotate] => 0
[text] => Hello
[fontFamily] => Twine
[color] => #000000
[colors] => Array
    (
        [0] => #000000 [svg] => <svg width="248" height="109" viewBox="-       2.48333740234375 0 248 109" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1U/" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="65" y="85" text-anchor="middle" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1">
 <tspan dy="0" x="49%">Hello</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

Comment: Does `echo $item['svg']` instead of `print_r` solves the problem?

Comment: other items in the array [type] => text
    [remove] => 1
    [rotate] => 0
    [text] => Hello
    [fontFamily] => Twine
    [color] => #000000
    [colors] => Array
        (
            [0] => #00

Comment: As far as I can see, all these properties (at least text and fontFamily) are already in the svg field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by print you mean display the actual SVG as part of HTML use echo instead

```
foreach($items as $item){
   echo $item['svg'];        
}
```

Comment: actualy there are other items in the array i didnt show bcoz of character limit

Comment: then it woul be: echo $item['svg'];